# How to break a function return chain

Tags: c++

I am writing a code having a recursive function. but it executes two time, actually i know why it is happening but i want to stop it please help...

```
int getMatrices()
{
    cout<<"Enter The Number Of Rows Of First Matrix : ";
    cin>>row_a;
    cout<<"Enter The Number Of Column Of First Matrix : ";
    cin>>column_a;
    cout<<"Enter The Number Of Rows Of Second Matrix (Can Not Be Different From Number Of Column Of First): ";
    cin>>row_b;
    cout<<"Enter The Number Of Column Of First Matrix : ";
    cin>>column_b;
    this->checkPhysibility(column_a, row_b);

    cout<<"\nEnter the first matrix : \n";
    fsor(int i=0;i<row_a;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<column_a;j++)
        {
            cout<<"\tA("<<i+1<<", "<<j+1<<") : ";
            cin>>a[i][j];   
        }
    cout<<"\nEnter the second matrix : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<row_b;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<column_b;j++)
        {
            cout<<"\tB("<<i+1<<", "<<j+1<<") : ";
            cin>>b[i][j];   
        }   
}
int checkPhysibility(int column_a, int row_b)
{
    if(column_a!=row_b)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nYou Entered Wrong Input, The Number Of Column Of First Matrix Can Not Be Different From Row Of Second Matrix For Making Their Multiplication Physible. Please Re-Enter The Values.\n\n";
        this->getMatrices();
    }

}
```

after calling checkPhysibility method it goes to check it but if goes in if statement and execute getMatrices again it makes a recursive chain and the code in getMatrices function (after the checkPhysibility call) executes twice which i wants to break. return statement doesn't work....

Comment: This is not **C**.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Could you make sure you're posting the real code? You should also be getting some warnings, like `checkPhysibility` never returns an integer. Fix them all, then see if you still have a problem. And, finally, show us a working class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the return type of `checkPhysibility` to `bool`.
2. I don't see the need for writing any messages in that function. Since `getMatrice` has all the code to get the data and write messages, it makese more sense to print the message in that function.
3. Change `getMatrices` to return if `checkPhysibility` returns `false`.
4. While you are at it, change `checkPhysibility` to `checkFeasibility`.

```
bool checkFeasibility(int column_a, int row_b)
{
   return (column_a == row_b);
}

int getMatrices()
{
   cout<<"Enter The Number Of Rows Of First Matrix : ";
   cin>>row_a;
   cout<<"Enter The Number Of Column Of First Matrix : ";
   cin>>column_a;
   cout<<"Enter The Number Of Rows Of Second Matrix (Can Not Be Different From Number Of Column Of First): ";
   cin>>row_b;
   cout<<"Enter The Number Of Column Of First Matrix : ";
   cin>>column_b;
   if ( false == checkFeasibility(column_a, row_b) )
   {
      cout<<"\n\nYou Entered Wrong Input, The Number Of Column Of First Matrix Can Not Be Different From Row Of Second Matrix For Making Their Multiplication Physible. Please Re-Enter The Values.\n\n";
      // ???
      return 0;
   }

   cout<<"\nEnter the first matrix : \n";
   fsor(int i=0;i<row_a;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<column_a;j++)
      {
         cout<<"\tA("<<i+1<<", "<<j+1<<") : ";
         cin>>a[i][j];   
      }
   cout<<"\nEnter the second matrix : \n";
   for(int i=0;i<row_b;i++)
      for(int j=0;j<column_b;j++)
      {
         cout<<"\tB("<<i+1<<", "<<j+1<<") : ";
         cin>>b[i][j];   
      }   

   // ???
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to pass a "depth" parameter.Increment by one on each call. Then you know which level the function is at.

The long answer is that this isn't a very good way to use recursion. If user input is wrong, jump back in a loop to re-enter it. Don't try to make a loop with recursion, at least in C / C++. Some people who program Lisp would tell you differently.